# Boolean 3 variables with if statement

Tags: java, boolean, logical-operators, boolean-operations

[The problem in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuiC5.jpg)
I have a problem, where I have to input a logical operator in the blanks while it still makes sense.

My first idea was to put &&, ! and &&, but that doesn't seem right

Answer (score 0):

Remember the General form of the Equation of a Circle:

```
x2 + y2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0
```

or

```
(x-a)^2+(x-b)^2 = r^2
```

"a" and "b" represents the center, and "r" is the radius.

In "one", we cover values within a circle with a radius of length 1 and with a center at the point (2, 2).
In "two" and "three" the center is at the point (0, 0).
"three" has a radius of 2:

```
x*x + y*y <= (2)^2
```

Then, "one" represents the circle on the upper right.
"two" is the little white circle at the center. "three" is the bigger gray circle.

So, I think that makes more sense:

```
if (one && !two && three)
  "gray"
else
  "white"
```